# EOF unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, eof

I have added this piece of code to upload files to a remote FTP.
and now I get an error: "line 58 syntax error: unexpected end of file"
individually it works

```
    #!/bin/bash    
    for fileupload in *.zip; do
    hostname="myhost"
    username="myuser"
    password="mypwd"
    ftp -vn $hostname <<ENDFTPCOMMAND
    quote USER $username
    quote PASS $password
    binary
    put $fileupload
    quit
    ENDFTPCOMMAND
    cd /home/user1/DATA/
    for fullname in DATAFILES/*.zip; do
    filename="${fullname##*/}"
    echo $filename
    line 57 done
```

Comment: can you post all the script, may be the problem is present in the not posted lines?

Comment: Why do you have "quote" in front of user and password? And I think you should put double quotes around "$fileupload"

Comment: @linuxcdeveloper i have update with similar small full line code

Comment: Please add some indentation to your code; nobody here even noticed you have 2 `for` loops, and only one `done`; which is another good explanation for your error, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop is not properly terminated. `done` needs to be preceded by a semicolon, or on a line by itself.

```
for fullname in DATAFILES/*.zip; do
filename="${fullname##*/}"
echo $filename
line 57
done
```

(On a side note, what is `line 57`?)

Comment: thank you 
Missing was the done after ENDFTPCOMMAND
the "line 57" is the line number of the done